# How dominant term helps determine time complexity using Big-O?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I don't quite understand the concept of dominant terms and how to determine the time complexity using big o. Like, for example, the dominant term of          N(100N + 200N^3) + N^3. If anyone could explain it, that would be very helpful.

Comment: It's the highest power of the expression. In your example - N^4.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a general question regarding algorithms, rather than a question about programming as defined by the [help]. Algorithm questions *not* about a specific programming problem can be asked on Computer Science.SE, instead.

Answer (score 9):

The dominant term is the term the one that gets biggest (i.e. *dominates*) as N gets bigger.

For example:

```
 N(100N + 200N^3) + N^3
```

can be rewritten as

```
 (100 * N^2) + (200 * N^4) + N^3
```

and as N gets very large, the N^4 is going to get biggest (irrespective of the 200 that you multiply it by).

So that would be O(N^4).

Comment: so, in terms of big o, what would it be? O(?)

Comment: @SomeoneAwesome it will be O(N^4)

Comment: @Stephen C, I also have one more question. What do you do when there is 'log' involved? Say for eg, 10MlogM + (N/2) log (N/2) + N/4??

Comment: @SomeoneAwesome log(N) is growing slower than N, but it grows (beats a constant function). Therefore, Nlog(N) is bigger than N but smaller than N^2. ϴ(10MlogM + (N/2) log (N/2) + N/4) = ϴ(MlogM + NlogN + N) = ϴ(MlogM + NlogN). That's where we end because we don't know more about M and N. Note that I used Theta, which is the exact class, unlike big-O, which is only an upper border. That said, you might want to do the following, first, read the definition (like f € O(g) <-> it exists c € R, n0 € N s.t. cg(n) >= f(n) for all n >= n0), understand it and compare some functions to each other.

Comment: @SomeoneAwesome For your comparison, take some basic functions you can think of, like f(x) = e^x or f(x) = x^2 or f(x) = sqrt(x), put some factor in front, create a table for such functions with some values inserted and find the points in time at which one overtakes the other. Then use those points to lay the graphs over each other. Will help you understand how they behave for large values.

Comment: @SomeoneAwesome Seeing that my definition of O(g) has a mistake, c is not element R but R+ of course.

Comment: "What do you do when there is 'log' involved?" - This is maths.  You can use maths to *prove* that (for example) an N log N term gets big faster than N, and N gets big faster than logN.  (Note that we are being very informal here.)  If you don't have the ability to do the mathematical proofs yourself, draw graphs of the functions, or find some web page that has collated and ordered the common complexity classes.

Answer (score 0):

Let `f(N) = 100N^2 + 200 N^4 + N^3`.  As `N` increases, the value of `f(N)` is dominated by the `200 N^4` term.  This would be the case even if coefficient of the `N^4` term was smaller than that of the lower order terms.

Consider the simpler example for `g(N) = N^2 + 4N`. When `N = 1000`, we get `g(1000) =10^6 + 4000` which is approximately `10^6` since a million plus a (few) thousand is still about a million.  So the `N^2$` term dominates the lower order terms. This would be the case even if the coefficients of the lower order terms are large - in `g(N) = N^2 + 10^{100} N`, `N^2` term dominates the linear term, and its just that the value of `N` required for the quadratic term to exceed the linear term is larger in this case. But as `N` goes to infinity, we can approximate a function by just its leading term.

As for big-oh notation, you can prove using its definition that a polynomial `f(N)` can be expressed as `O(N^k)`, where `k` is the exponent in the leading term. In your example, we can say `f(N) = O(N^4)`.  This notation discards the lower order terms and the coefficient of the leading term as they are often irrelevant when comparing different algorithms for their running time.

Comment: What are all these $ signs for?

Comment: @TDG I thougt those $ signs would be converted to equation form, like it does on other communities (such as math.stackexchange.com) I am a part of. That's latex stuff.

Comment: I see. In here it's a ` sign. Anyway, I've edited your answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Dominant" simply means "the one that grows faster in the long run". That's the best way I can put it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's devise your polynomial function into parts ,
F(N) = 100N²+ 200N^4 + N^3 ;
g,h,k are respectively 3 polynomial functions
g(N) = 200N^4 , h(N) = N^3 , k(N) = 100N² .
h is dominated by g , and k is dominated by h , so using Transitive relation k is dominated by g ; so both h and k are dominated by g.
I mean by domination in mathematics , the limit of the fraction (h(n) / g(n) ) or ( k(n) / g(n) )  if n goes to infinity : is zero.
so to know which function is dominated , you need to study the asymptotic behavior and limits.

This is an example illustrated from [this website](https://www.nagwa.com/en/videos/957135971258/)

[image]